# React Native app does not crash as expected

Tags: react-native, crash

We have been investigating issues in our app where we just see a white screen and no crash is logged. Goes for both Android and iOS

The issue seem to be related to the use of async/await or promises.

We have found that we can reproduce the white screen issue locally when using async/await or promises.

The issue can be reproduced with the following code (tried to simplify it as much as possible). Replace App.js in a new project with the following:

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {isMounted: false};

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Promise.resolve(1);
    this.setState({isMounted: true});
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isMounted) {
      this.state.isMounted.test();
    }
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Text>test</Text>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also pushed a [test project](https://github.com/remanation/exceptiontest) on github

I would expect the app to crash as `isMounted` does not contains a `test` method.

When running locally I get the red box stating that an error occurred as expected

```
TypeError: this.state.isMounted.test is not a function. (In 'this.state.isMounted.test()', 'this.state.isMounted.test' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in App (at renderApplication.js:40)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:98)
    in RCTView (at View.js:35)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:115)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

...
```

but when running a release build the app does not crash and no error is reported. This makes it very hard for us to find and fix issues like this as we are totally blind.

If I comment out

```
await Promise.resolve(1);
```

It crash as expected in a release build

React Native version: 0.60.5

Are we wrong in assuming that the above code should result in an app crash?

Comment: What are you expecting `await Promise.resolve(1)` to do?   It seems the issue is that `isMounted` is not getting set to `true` which is why it's not crashing.

Comment: It is not important what `await Promise.resolve(1)` do. I just used that to simplify the example. It could be a call to the fetch api instead. isMounted is set to true just fine, because if I run it in debug I get the red error box and if I run it in release I can in the Xcode output windows see the following error `[error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] TypeError: this.state.isMounted.test is not a function. (In 'this.state.isMounted.test()', 'this.state.isMounted.test' is undefined)` The problem is that the error is seen as a non-fatal error and thereby does not crash the app

Answer (score 1):

Found that [error-boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) was the missing piece. Implementing an error boundary on the root level allows us to manually log these errors to our crash handling system.

As a side note I can also mention that if you use [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) and you throw an error, the error by default seem to be swallowed. So if you want to handle these uncaught errors you can implement the `onError` option in `createSagaMiddleware`